# Two identical CGSize's and one appears smaller

Tags: ios, swift

I have an ImageView and I have a CustomView that I want to appear the same size on screen.

```
public override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
progress.frame.size = circle.frame.size
print("Progress frame size w: \(progress.frame.size.width) h: \(progress.frame.size.height)
print("Circle frame size w: \(circle.frame.size.width) h: \(circle.frame.size.height)

//Progress frame size w: 300 h: 300
//Circle frame size w: 300 h: 300
```

and yet they appear with different size on the Simulator:

[image]

I tried setting the bounds instead of frame. I also tried calculating the difference from the view to the circle and setting the progress frame according to that:

```
let widthDifference = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - circle.frame.size.width
let progressWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - widthDifference
...
```

but no success.

I don't know what's happening, I am really new to iOS development and many things are weird to me.

The size of the progress bar was fine when the scene was wrapped in a NavigationController. When I removed the NavigationController the dimensions were totally screwed.

FYI: Circle is an image view. Progress is a [third-party circular progress bar](https://www.google.com/search?q=kdcircularprogress&oq=KDCircular&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.12782j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your progress bar is indeed the same size of your circle but that doesn't mean that the bar will take the full size of 300px for diameter.

If you are curious, take a look at this [line from the library](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress/blob/ba525189fb2dd2b3e0ebbd8ccac77bf2e5915739/KDCircularProgress/KDCircularProgress.swift#L442), [and also this line](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress/blob/ba525189fb2dd2b3e0ebbd8ccac77bf2e5915739/KDCircularProgress/KDCircularProgress.swift#L426) to see how the radius is created.

You can also try to print out the value of `arcRadius` and it must be smaller than 150px.

Comment: Okay thanks, the math sounds legit. But I can't locate the arcRadius on the progress bar. I see it's added through `addArc()` method but I can't find how to get the value, or even better: **how to set it**. All I could dig is that it's a method in CGContext, but again I can't see how to get it even from there.

Comment: I found from [this line](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress/blob/ba525189fb2dd2b3e0ebbd8ccac77bf2e5915739/KDCircularProgress/KDCircularProgress.swift#L223) that I should add 20% to the size, but I'd be happy if you point where I can learn more about this.

Comment: @Kokolo Wow great findings! Not sure what do you mean by where you can learn this but... The bottom line is this is a library you are using and it is provided to you as is. If the original author does not provide a way for you to change this default 20%, you can't do anything about it....Actually you can do something. I assume you are using cocoa-pods. Just fork this project and change remove the padding line. Then ask cocoa-pods to point to your forked & modified version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I just learned I can fork the library and use it as my own through cocoa-pods. Feel free to add those to your answer. Marking as best anyway.